VS Code Azure function error: inputStream should be at start of stream
I've developed the Azure function below, which is blob triggered and it PGP encrypts the file received in an inbound container and places the encrypted file into an outbound container.
in Visual Studio 2022, it works fine on my local machine.
I then created a project in VS Code and copied the same code across, VS code throws the error:

inputStream should be at start of stream.

Function code:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using PgpCore;

public class Function1
{
    private readonly string keyVaultName = "MyKV";
    private readonly string keyName = "SKEY";
    private readonly string outboundContainerName = "OutBound";

    [FunctionName("BlobTriggerFunction")]
    public async Task Run(
        [BlobTrigger("Inbound/{name}.txt", Connection = "Devsandpit")] Stream inblobStream,
        string name,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {inblobStream.Length} Bytes");

        // Get PGP public key from Azure Key Vault
        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(keyName);
        string publicKey = secret.Value;

        // Decode the Base64 encoded public key
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);

        // Using MemoryStream for the public key
        using (MemoryStream publicKeyStream = new MemoryStream(publicKeyBytes))
        using (Stream outputFileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Initialize PGP encryption keys and PGP utility
            EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(publicKeyStream);
            PGP pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);

            // Prepare the input data for encryption
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await inblobStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            
            // Encrypt the data stream
            await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(inblobStream, outputFileStream);
            outputFileStream.Position = 0;

            // Upload encrypted file to outbound container
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Devsandpit"));
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(outboundContainerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(name);

            await blobClient.UploadAsync(outputFileStream, new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "application/octet-stream" });
        }
    }
}

Expecting the function to work in VS Code the same way it worked in VS Studio 2022.

Use VS Code debugger to work out which line it is failing on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

For anyone who's facing a similar issue, Adding this line to the code resolved it :
 // Create a MemoryStream for encrypted data
        MemoryStream outputFileStream = new MemoryStream();

